# Replace list with list created in rep

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this code

```
nd = 100
scores$data = factor(rep(c("wine", "beer", "coffee", "soda"), nd))
```

but instead of listing it one by one wine beer coffee and soda  ,is there another way of putting a list in there instead? for example .

```
keywordName = list("wine", "beer", "coffee", "soda")
scores$data = factor(rep(c(keywordName), nd))
```

however , this didnt work for me . 
is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I think only if you `unlist` it first (but then why use a list at all?). `factor` needs an atomic vector, I think, because it needs to sort the elements, and it can't assume that a list only contains a single type of data.

Comment: (btw, it _is_ somewhat unfortunate that `sort.list` won't sort lists.)

Comment: Note that `rep(c(keywordName), nd)` will be a list of length 100, not 400 like `rep(c("wine", "beer", "coffee", "soda"), nd)`. How may rows is `scores` supposed to have?

Comment: oh.... my bad 
alright lets see....
my problem here is just i want another way of adding in the wine beer coffee soda into the factor . and okay lets say the list length is 400 and the scores length is 400 .

Comment: alright used , unlist and i think it's working . thanks joran :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully i explained my self correctly
I basically just used unlisted(keywordName) in the code . the nd is actually calculated somewhere else .
so my problem was like , since i can calculate the nd perfectly and get my scores correctly , but the type of keywords
i'm gonna list in it is quite dynamic and i had no idea how to store all these keywords on a list and then just
call it out there instead of hard-coding it one by one.

So my solution was to pass a list of these keywords which can be stored in any way you choose, and then just use unlist to put the keywords in.

```
      eg;
      keywordName = c("pepsi","coke")  
      scores$data = factor(rep(c(unlist(keywordName)), nd))
```